# SQL - 2 Joins in one statement

Tags: sql, join

Quick Question here. I am trying to SELECT peron_name and person_profession and person member_role from 3 different tables.
Right Now, this is working:

```
SELECT a.per_FirstName AS Nome
     , pc.c1 as Profissao
     , a.per_cls_ID as Membro 
FROM person_per AS a 
LEFT JOIN person_custom pc ON a.per_id = pc.per_ID 
ORDER BY pc.c1
     , a.per_FirstName
```

But it is giving me the member_role as the member_code ID. I have another table called list_lst that relates per_cls_ID to a specific role. How do I reference it?

Right now, my query prints:

```
JohnDoe      Doctor    2  
MaryJane    Teacher    1
```

I want it to print:

```
JohnDoe    Doctor    Member
MaryJane    Teacher    Visitor
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You would do this with another join. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ You also should decide which DBMS you are using as mysql is not the same thing as sql server.

Comment: How is it that you were able to JOIN the person_custom table, but you cannot join the list_lst table?   What is so different about this other table that you cannot join it the same way as the first???

Answer (score 1):

It is something like:

```
SELECT 
    a.per_FirstName AS Nome, 
    pc.c1 as Profissao, 
    l.COLUMNNAMEHERE as Membro 
FROM person_per AS a 
LEFT JOIN person_custom pc ON a.per_id = pc.per_ID 
LEFT JOIN list_lst l on l.per_cls_ID = a.per_cls_ID
ORDER BY pc.c1, a.per_FirstName
```